# how can I set android app never show usb access dialog again

Tags: android, usb

I got this dialog and following problem by android app: 

if I click "ok" and use by default for this usb device,
it will no prompt again,
but when I turn off and then turn on my pad it will prompt again.

> **How can I let usb access dialog  never show again?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that **you can't**. USB data connections require user validation, and can't be overriden programmatically. If the user chooses to select the option `Use by default for this USB device` then the dialog box will not appear again. But you can't override that validation programmatically.

Comment: no, it can only be solved by re-compiling Android with changes to some of the framework classes. Neither this nor rooting is an option anyway because you have to assume that users of your app have the default, non-rooted OS in their phones.